# WPML with WP_Query serving up all 3 languages

Tags: custom-post-types, multisite, wp-query, plugin-wpml

I've got something about this on the WPML support forums, but I figured I could ask here as well.  Here's the important info:  I'm running a WP Multisite setup with custom post types, custom fields, custom everything it seems.  In a particular template file, I've got a secondary loop that's pulling a list of items from a different blog.  From what I gathered, anything using the WP API should be filtered down to only the current language, but none of the `WP_Query()` functions I've got are doing so.

Relevant code:

```
<?php 
 switch_to_blog(23);
$args = array('post_type' => 'release-notes',
    'suppress_filters' => 0,
    'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'related_products',
                'value' => $thisproduct,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
if ($loop->have_posts()) {
    echo '<h2>Release Notes</h2>';
    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
        //echo '<pre>';
        //print_r($post);
        //echo '</pre>';
        $post_link = ($post->post_name);
        echo '<p><a class="text-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></p>';
    endwhile; // foreach($posts
} // if ($results
restore_current_blog();
?>
```

The problem here is twofold: first, it's returning results from every language instead of the current language - the same post, three times (EN, FR, DE).  Second, the result from `get_permalink()` is completely wrong - it's spitting out http://www.mysite.com/blog23name/postname instead of http://www.mysite.com/blog23name/lang/posttype/postname - the custom permalink shown on the 'edit post' page.

Any ideas?

Comment: IMO, it's not fair to ask premium plugin questions here...

Comment: "Not fair"?  In what way?  Why would there be a tag for WPML if it couldn't be asked here?  Check the FAQ again, mate.  It's licensed under the GPL (even the premium version), so technically I could post any relevant code chunks for others to look at for troubleshooting.  That said, at least one of the issues is a core WordPress issue - `switch_to_blog()` doesn't pass over permalinks for custom post types with `get_permalink()` - making this a great place to ask about it.  Thanks for the downvote, though, it's much more helpful than actually coming up with an answer to a 2 month old question.

Comment: Do they have a "free version"? If they do, sorry, I was not aware... If they don't, having a Tag doesn't excuse any GPL...

Comment: No free version - doesn't matter.  The paid version is licensed under the GPL.  http://wpml.org/faq-tags/license/  Yes, it's a paid plugin.  No, that's not again the rules, nor is it "not fair".  Think paid plugins have no place here?  Take it to Meta and convince them that paid plugins can't be discussed here - http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1067/extend-faq-to-deny-support-for-stolen-not-paid-commercial-plugins-themes.  Don't downvote a valid question because you don't believe it should be valid, especially 2 months later on an unanswered question.

Comment: This is in the scope of this site and ok to ask question like this one here but since you paid for support you should really ask them for it and i guess they can help with their own plugin better then most of us here, (but the question is perfectly valid here)

Comment: Yes, I should have taken it to the Meta before downvoting, now I cannot undo it. Thanks for claryfying, @Bainternet. SickHippie, looks like you haven't got an answer at their forum yet, hope some good soul, while revising old questions, stumbles upon this one and upvote it. Best regards and sorry for the mistake.

Comment: @Bainternet I did ask them about it, and their support staff gave me a couple basic troubleshooting steps over 2 days before I worked around it with a SQL query.  As I said, the permalink issue turned out to be a core WordPress bug (that won't be fixed, as it causes server resource issues), and I still have no workaround for that.  So it goes.

Comment: @brasofilo - no worries, mate.  I was a bit overstressed yesterday, and apologize for my aggressive attitude.  It was uncalled for, and I'm very sorry.

Comment: Can you please post the SQL Query your `WP_Query` object produces? Maybe we will see something there. I had a similar issue on a site of mine, it's not always clear what's happening (at least not to me ;) )

Comment: Solution below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to register the custom post types on the site where I'm calling it from, then in WPML's settings set them to translate.  This is in WPML -> Translation Management -> Multilingual Content Setup, down at the bottom.  I assume it works by tricking WP into using that site's rewrite/translate rules when it doesn't have the proper info from `switch_to_blog()`.