# Removing an admin page added by a 3rd party plugin. Gravity forms in this example

Tags: plugins, wp-admin, admin-menu, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to hide a help page from editors, added by the [gravity forms](http://www.gravityforms.com/) plugin. I believe I've run into the same issue before with other plugins, so I'd like to know the correct way to do it for 3rd party plugins. This is what I have so far which does not work. It does of course work for other WP menus so I'm wondering if the function is only limited to WP menus?

```
function remove_menu_links() {
  if( !current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
    remove_menu_page('admin.php?page=gf_help'); // this is the pages url
  }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, Eugene's Answer works in the case of a plugin that doesn't deals with custom capabilities.

> <sup>http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities</sup>
> The [WordPress Plugin API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API) allows Roles and Capabilities to be added, removed and changed. Since Plugins might change Roles and Capabilities, just the default ones are addressed in this article.

---

So, if his code works without checking for the capability, we have to look how GravityForms executes his `add_submenu_page` action.
And for that, we drop the whole plugin folder inside a good code editor (NotePad++, TextMate, etc) and do a global search and find our stuff.

```
// wp-content/plugins/gravityforms/gravityforms.php
// all parameters removed from the original code, except $page_title and $capability
add_submenu_page( 
    $parent_slug, 
    __("Help", "gravityforms"),
    $menu_title,
    $has_full_access ? "gform_full_access" : $min_cap, 
    $menu_slug, 
    $function 
);
```

And a few lines before we see:

```
$has_full_access = current_user_can("gform_full_access");
$min_cap = GFCommon::current_user_can_which(GFCommon::all_caps());
if(empty($min_cap))
    $min_cap = "gform_full_access";
```

---

Now we go ahead with [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin, which btw GF recognizes, and we have the following in its config screen for the Editor role.
**BUT NOTING THAT** `gform_full_access` doesn't appears in this list. It has to be manually added through the plugin interface...

[image]

After that and marking the full access capability, the `remove_submenu_page` works as expected to the Editor role.

---

---

Reference code for all submenus (remembering the first one is the very top menu).

```
function remove_menu_links() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_edit_forms' ); 
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_new_form' ); 
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_new_formf_help' ); 
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_entries' ); 
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_settings' ); 
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_export' ); 
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_update' ); 
        // remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_addons' ); 
        remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_help' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links', 9999 );
```

---

#### Plugin of interest

[Adminimize](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/adminimize) does this hiding magic in the blink of an eye and is completely PRO.

Comment: thank you for your comprehensive answer and for looking into the source of GF. I've now added the `gform_full_access` capability and the help has gone as expected. It does open up another can of worms in that all the other menu links are now accessible but I've hidden them all with the function :) I've had this problem in the past with disabling 3rd party menu links but I think I'm a lot more comfortable with it now.

Comment: @Andrew : I missed a couple of issues and updated my answer. Looks like the help page is considered pretty harmless and available to all caps `current_user_can_which(GFCommon::all_caps())`.. .. .. If you really want to block the access and not only hide the menu, probably some `admin_head` or `admin_init` coupled with `current_user_can`, `$pagenow` and `wp_die` could do the job.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add your hook at the end of the queue and then remove menu by slug:

```
function remove_menu_links() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_menu_page( 'gf_edit_forms' ); // this is the pages url
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links', 9999 );
```

If you want to remove submenu you need to use following snippet:

```
function remove_menu_links() {
    if( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
        remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_help' ); 
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links', 9999 );
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't seem to work though. Any other ideas?

Comment: Probably you want to remove submenu item. I have updated my answer and added snippet to remove submenu item.

Comment: I was unsuccessful with that also. The problem seems to be that it doesn't have a top menu slug. The full url when I hover over the link is http://website.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=gf_help

Comment: @Andrew : Just edited the code and the `remove_*` works ok. The question is: do editors have GravityForms capability? . . . 'Cause that doesn't seem to be true.

Comment: I know it doesn't sound helpful .... If @Andrew has paid for Gravity Forms he can probably find the answer about capabilities and roles in their FAQ's or you can ask this info direct to Gravity Forms support

Comment: @brasofilo Still doesn't seem to work for me. Editors don't have the GF capability by default, but I've given them the `gravityforms_view_entries` capability which allows them to look at the entries of the form. Unfortunately, this also adds the help menu which I'm trying to get rid of :)

Comment: @Damien Yeah, I've posted numerous messages on their forums but most of them never seem to get answered

Comment: @Damien : If the question is relative to a menu that any given plugin is inserting into WP, then the question most likely will be ok. A [Comments War](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/48244/12615) happened between me and SickHippie for a WPML Q he posted, and I've learned that some premium Questions are perfectly valid here. . . . . Also, those are pretty popular plugins (GF, BackupBuddy, WMPL) and have a large user base here who may be able to help. I pay for those 3, and GF is damn good, literally saved my arse in a complex setup I was almost deadly stuck. My 2¢ :)

Comment: @Andrew - ¿Have you tested *without* the `current_user_can` condition? That **does works** for me. . . . Sometimes, even the calls in premium support forums fall in deaf ears... A good tip, exactly just like here in the Stack, is to work out the Title and the Content of the topic: `succinct + explicit + well formatted & referenced == more_chances_to_get_a_good_answer(true);`

Comment: @brasofilo Interestingly enough it does work without the `current_user_can` (yay). But only for me as an `administrator`. If I log out, then login as an `editor` or use the user switching plugin, the editor STILL has the help menu, hah... really confused now. I'm the admin with way more capabilities so how on earth would the editor still have the help menu :)

Comment: Oh and good point about the members plugin "seeing" the capabilities by default. User role editor used to, but for some reason it doesn't anymore.

Comment: @brasofilo point taken ... i didn't mean anything negative by my comment. I've paid for a developers licence for Gravity Forms and always found that they've got back to me in < 24 hours. i *think* there is a page on GF dedicated to the hooks and roles & permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The GravityForms plugin renames the top level menu item to match the first of the sub-menu.

For example; if you've added just the *gravityforms_view_entries* capability to the Editor role, then the first sub-menu item will be "Entries", so the parent menu will be "gf_entries" not "gf_edit_forms". So, the following code will remove the "Help" item from the sub-menu for Editors with just that capability:

```
function remove_menu_links() {
    remove_submenu_page( 'gf_entries', 'gf_help' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'remove_menu_links', 9999 )
;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This was driving me insane. The answers provided here got me most of the way, but that particular darned Gravity Forms menu item is a little weird.

I managed to get to the root of it by analysing the $submenu global variable which contains all the menu data. The following snippet should kill the update submenu item for you, when hooked into admin_menu() as listed above :)

```
remove_submenu_page( 'gf_edit_forms', 'gf_update' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing above worked for me, but at least I can hide it with CSS.

#toplevel_page_gf_help{display:none;}

Answer (score 0):

you can hide it with css only if you want,
search for a plugin to add css on admin panel :

```
a[href="admin.php?page=gf_help"] {
    display: none !important;
}
```